# Remove languages in translations?

Tags: language-support, internationalization, spell-checking

I use spell-checker for 4 languages, `en`, `de`, `fr`, and `lb`.

If I enable `Spellchecking and writing aids` for `en`, `de` or `fr` in `System -> Administration -> Language Support` there will be multiple versions of each language available, e.g. `en` , `en_CA`, `en_GB`, ...

[image]

Is there a possibility to select only one of those language versions while enabling the language, or removing the others afterwards. It would be enough to remove them from the selection menu.

I would like to use the version which is equal to the country the language originally comes from: e.g. `de_DE`, `fr_FR`, `en_GB`. For `lb` there is currently only `lb_LU` so there is no problem (yet).

Instead of 4 languages I currently have around 20, which is kind of annoying when switching the language ( which I do quite often).

There might be a similar problem for the menu translations, where if I understand correctly you can choose the order in which translations are applied if they exist.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me, is de-installing the aspell dictionary, because it contains all four English versions in one package, and then installing/de-installing the localized dictionary’s for hunspell. so you can choose to only install the en_EN but leave en_CA uninstalled . And because Synaptic gave me no dependency warning when de-installing aspell plus its dictionaries it should still work in all programs.

[edit] only works for english. french, and german are also all-in-one packages for myspell/hunspell

[edit2] what now really works, but may not be the best solution:

delete de dictionaries/links to dictionaries from /usr/share/myspell & /usr/share/hunspell after de-installing aspell. Only flaw may be that hunspell only has an en_US dictionary, but no british version

[image]

Comment: I confirm that deleting `aspell-en` does not warn for dependencies, but ff I search for `hunspell` in synaptic I only see `hunspell-en-ca` and `hunspell-en-us`. Where are Australia, South Africa and United Kingdom? I don't really want to delete directories manually. But will try if the first solution works for English.

Comment: It seems to work. There are still some issue: French being twice in the list, German (Luxembourg) as well as English (United States) still being there. But I should be able to figure that one out too. http://i.imgur.com/cZt2N.png

Comment: deleting dictionaries/links to dictionaries from `/usr/share/myspell` & `/usr/share/hunspell` did the trick for me. i could otherwise not remove the many flavors versions of the french and spanish dictionaries.